# When adding an Admin to the Application, I get the error message NAME is not a verified user - even though the user is

Tags: facebook, roles

I have an issue with adding a developer colleague to the application as an administrator (it doesn't matter if he's added in a developer role, the error stays the same).

Even though the colleague has a verified account with Facebook that he uses, Facebook claims when I try to add him that he "is not a verified" user.

I assume this is a bug, as the account was disabled once by the user (not by Facebook) and has been reactivated.

Who could I contact to sort this issue out?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, well, it is https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/545/ just try to log-out or use an incognito mode while visiting http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ and read the welcome message.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, you still correct about programming question, what we see here is not programming and not technical question!

Comment: @Juicy Scripter: I also thought a while before submitting it, but in my view it was a question regarding how to enable programming on the FB platform. Apologies if there is a disagreement about this.

Comment: @BjoernSjut, I think the major disagreement is not what you want to be answered but what you're asking for. _«Who could I contact to sort this issue out?»_ - is a really bad question for SO...

Answer (score 19):

The other developer will need to verify himself as a Developer by going to http://developers.facebook.com/ before you can add him.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the quick reply - that actually wasn't the driver. We just found out that Facebook apparently requires a phone-verified account for developers. After adding a verified phone number to the colleagues facebook account I was able to add him as a developer. That error message should really be more clear that this is about the phone number...

Comment: @BjoernSjut, you doesn't have to provide a phone, there is another option too - credit card ;-}

Comment: Yes, the push to "verify" is so vague that I remember going through the same headache once before.  Hope it all worked out!

Answer (score 12):

As described here:

https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=167551763306531

you need to prove yourself worthy via a phone # or credit card.